# Who keeps track of science?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

Who keeps the track of all the scientific facts and theories, what authority keeps the evidence? Where are all the scientific resources centralized(it seems they should be) and accessible? Are they in libraries, in universities, in the governmental institutions computers, where? Moreover, what authority in the whole wide world decides what is and what isn't science?

Comment: I beleive that you answered your own questions already. Except for that the scientific community keeps track of itself, trough peer reviews and keeping to scientific methods.

Comment: What is peer review and who is the scientific community composed of?

Comment: Scientific community is composed of people, who according to set standarts are knowledgable in one or more scientific fields. Standarts for what constitutes adequate knowledge are agreed upon by people who have the before-mentioned knowledge. Peer review is a process carried out by people knowledgable in the field, where they review and check for errors/inconsistencies works of otber specialists in the same field

Comment: Oh that makes so much sense...So, if a guy, not necessarily well known throughout the scientific community discovers or develops a theory, what is the next step he has to take? Where is he supposed to go?

Comment: This seems a better for for Academia.SE. The short answer (or my understanding of it at least) is that it can be challenging without either an academic or industry connection to "the community."

Comment: @RemusCristian Perhaps to someone who IS known in the scientific community. Then again, if someone is virtually unknown in the mentioned community, he might be dismissed based solely on the fact of him not being known and lacking repuation. Yes, without a formal academic structure it gets more complicated than necessary.

Comment: I voted this up because as the answer below puts it "The question of what constitutes science and what doesn't is an open question in philosophy"

Answer (score 4):

> Who keeps the track of all the scientific facts and theories, what authority keeps the evidence?

There is no official authority that keeps track of everything. The results of science are recorded in academic and scientific journals, which in turn are archived by university and research institution libraries. Most journals now also have online versions where you can access there published papers. The http://arxiv.org is an open access resource which is one place to go for copies of scientific papers (unreviewed drafts, as well as copies of those that have been accepted in the regular journals). [JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org) is another resource for more general subjects, including science (although it is not free like the arxiv).

> Moreover, what authority in the whole wide world decides what is and what isn't science?

The question of what constitutes science and what doesn't is an open question in philosophy, known as the [demarcation problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demarcation_problem). Here in the US at least, there are several institutes which oversee how science is conducted, such as the NSF, the NIH, the FDA, the CDC, etc...

I don't know whether theses institutes have an explicit stance on the demarcation problem, and whether they use explicit definitions of what is science and what isn't. They do however exert significant control of how public funds are used for research and as such indirectly control what is considered legitimate research and what isn't, thereby defining what are considered legitimate scientific questions and what aren't. I doubt for example that the NSF will ever accept a research grant proposal for telekinesis research or creationist mathematical simulations, nor would the NIH accept a request for funding of Qi based healing research.

Comment: Who do these journals belong to? If a scientist makes a discovery or develops a theory or something, where is he supposed to go?

Comment: Note that arxiv is techincally "pre-prints" -- almost none of those papers have  gone through the peer review process prior to being made available there.

Comment: @RemusCristian some of them are for profit organizations like Sciencedirect or springerverlag, others are noprofit associations, like the ieee or AAAS

Comment: @Dave a lot of none reviewed stuff on the arxiv , but also I have been able to find anything that I didn't have access on the official sites mirrored (up to a some formatting differences) on the arxiv

Comment: Re: the demarcation problem: [This text](http://www.nap.edu/read/6024/chapter/2) from the National Academy of Sciences (http://www.nasonline.org) provides an interesting, "semi-official" popular description of what constitutes "Science" from a well-respected body that covers all scientific fields (this text is focusing on Science vs. creationism though). It also contains definitions of concepts such as 'theory', 'fact' and 'hypothesis'. Even if it is general and not very specific, it is still interesting to have as a reference point.

Answer (score 1):

> Who keeps track of science?

The short answer: The scientists themselves keep track of science.

The means are publications, conferences and appointments to academic positions. Hence it is not the single scientist, but the community of sciencists who determine the path of their subject.

On a more abstract level, Kuhn in his seminal essay *Kuhn, Thomas: The Structure of Scientific Revolutions.* (1962) discriminates two different phases of science: The normal phase, where all scientists work according to a well-established paradigm. And the revolutionary phase with the successfull proposal and implementation of a groundbreaking new paradigm.

> Where are all the scientific resources centralized and accessible?

The results are published in scientific journals, which are peer-reviewed, and also as e-prints at servers like http://arxiv.org/ But results from certains domain, e.g., from military research, are not freely accessible.

> What authority in the whole wide world decides what is and what isn't science?

The community of scientists, often in the next generations.